# Get static field from nested class via expression tree

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression-trees

I have these classes:

```
public class Entity
{
    public static readonly EntitySchema Schema = new EntitySchema();
}

public abstract class BaseSchema
{
    public abstract string Name {get;}
}

public class EntitySchema : BaseSchema
{
    public override string Name => "Schema";
}
```

Now, I want to access `EntitySchema.Name` from a method, which does not know anything about Entity (cannot access the static field).

I could do this with reflection:

```
static BaseSchema GetSchema<T>()
{
    var pr = typeof(T).GetField("Schema");
    var schema = pr.GetValue(null);
    return schema as BaseSchema;
}
```

but compared to a direct call `Entity.Schema.Name` the reflection version is **50x slower**.

Is there a way to convert the reflection version into an Expression Tree and pre-compile the call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can do that, but .NET requires to have the full field definition (`EntitySchema global::Entity.Schema` in this case) to get the actual value. Reflection gets you this definition. You'd need to make a delegate for every type, ie:

```
public static class SchemaGetter
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<object, Func<BaseSchema>> _lookup = new Dictionary<object, Func<BaseSchema>>();

    public static BaseSchema Get<T>()
    {
        Func<BaseSchema> action;

        if(!_lookup.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out action))
        {
            action = MakeDelegate<T>();

            _lookup.Add(typeof(T), action);
        }

        return action();            
    }

    private static Func<BaseSchema> MakeDelegate<T>()
    {
        // We did this before already...

        FieldInfo field = typeof(T).GetField("Schema", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        var fieldExpression = Expression.Field(null, field);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<BaseSchema>>(fieldExpression);

        return lambda.Compile();
    }
}
```

Followed by `BaseSchema schema = SchemaGetter.Get<Entity>()` to get the actual schema.

Perhaps its sufficient enough to cache the result that you've got from your initial `GetSchema<T>()` implementation (wrap it in a dictionary lookup). I think it must in this case, since the field is static anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Running the compiled version of var f = MakeDelegate<Entity>() is now about 44ms for 10mio calls, instead of 1250ms!